# Assigning a dictionary to a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

When check self.weatherData, I get nothing even though there is data in "data". Here is my function:

```
- (void)handleNetworkResponse:(NSData *)myData
{
    //NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
    id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    // typecast an array and list its contents
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *)myJSON;

    // take a look at all elements in the array
    for (id element in jsonArray) {

        id key = [element description];

        id innerArr = [jsonArray objectForKey:key];

        NSDictionary *inner = (NSDictionary *)innerArr;

        if ([inner conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSFastEnumeration)]) {

            for(id ele in inner) {

                id innerKey = [ele description];
                [data setObject:[[inner valueForKey:innerKey] description] forKey:[ele description]];
            }
        }
        else {

            [data setObject:[inner description] forKey:[element description]];
        }
    }

    NSLog([data description]);
    self.weatherData = data;
}
```

However when check self.weatherData, I get nothing even though there is data in "data".

Comment: using arc? make sure that property is 'strong'

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *weatherData;

Comment: this is my property still not working...

Comment: Your method `handleNetworkResponse:` has lot of mistakes. Everywhere taking description of objects, and for array giving type as NSDictionary... lot of mistakes.. Are you a beginner?

Comment: Does this log: NSLog([data description]); show anything? BTW, your log statements should start with a format string, and there's no reason to use "description" -- NSLog(@"%@",data) is the correct way to write it.

Comment: The first thing you should check is the content of myJSON. So put in a log NSLog(@"%@",myJSON) and see what that gives you. Also check its class.

Comment: I am a beginner. I can see all the data correctly by using NSLog([data description]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was data isn't there when I assign it to the variable from the an asynchronous method :D
all fixed now by adding a delegate call back